# Trying to get [a-z] part of redirect to work in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Here's my current .htaccess file contents:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN wtwp_cache
# END wtwp_cache
# BEGIN wtwp_security
# END wtwp_security

Redirect 301 /2016/03/26/alex-bayne-2-ohio-state/ http://website.com/softball/alex-bayne-2-ohio-state/ #REDIRECT **WORKS** FINE
Redirect 301 /tag/southpaw-throws-left/ http://website.com/softball-tag/southpaw-throws-left/ #REDIRECT **WORKS** FINE

RewriteRule ^/tag/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /softball-tag/$1 [NC,R=301,L] #REDIRECT **DOESN'T WORK**
```

What I'm trying to do is redirect */**tag**/ANYTHING-AFTER* to */**softball-tag**/ANYTHING-AFTER* and the URL keeps all same content except replaces /**tag**/ with /**softball-tag**/

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /softball-tag/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

No slash at the beginning of the url, in htaccess test RewriteRule.

Comment: Thanks for respone but `RewriteRule ^tag/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /softball-tag/$1 [NC,R=301,L]` is not working for me. Any thoughts? I added it to `.htaccess` and am testing by putting _website.com/tag/bla/_ in browser but it's not redirecting to _website.com/softball-tag/bla/_

Comment: Yes. You have to put this rule first, just after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Very nice. Thanks @Croises! Curious why does the `Redirect 301` work lower in file but `RewriteRule` has to be at top?

Comment: Not the same module. And you must place it before basic rewrite of all non-existent pages. Because otherwise it is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want, including `QSA` so the ?query is preserved too.

```
RewriteRule ^tag(/.*|$) /softball-tag$1 [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
```

*Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ftxDit/1*